# How can I solve if-else problem in for loops python3?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

```
list = [["alex","tiffany"],["richard","bella"],["bruno","jessica"]]

enter = input("enter name: ")

for i in list:

    if enter == i[0]:

        print(i[1])

    else:

        print("the name that you searched for is absent!")

    break
```

Output 1:

```
enter name: alex

->tifanny
```

Output 2:

```
enter name: richard

->the name that you searched for is absent!
```

I want to print "bella" but my program doesn't do this. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Think about the loop logic - if it's not in the first sub list, do you really want to print that it wasn't found? Break out of the loop?

Comment: firstly dont use the variable name `list` list is actually a built in keyword, secondly does it need to be a list of lists? a dict would be a better data structure here

Comment: thank you so much for your help I understand the problem anymore and I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

- The `break` was in the wrong place.
- Double-spacing the lines is against standard formatting standards
- Single-letter variable name should only be used for index variables
- Naming a variable `list` conflicts with the `list` type which could be imported.
- You need to keep track of whether the name was found or not

To learn more about standards for writing Python programs, read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); you could also get to know a Python linter like [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/).

Here is a working program. It could still be better, but I wanted to keep the program recognizable to you:

```py
names = [["alex","tiffany"],["richard","bella"],["bruno","jessica"]]
name = input("Enter name: ")
found = False
for item in names:
    if name == item[0]:
        print(item[1])
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    print("The name that you searched for is absent!")
```

Here it is in action:

```
$ python x.py
Enter name: richard
The name that you searched for is absent!
bella
The name that you searched for is absent!

$ python x.py
Enter name: richard
bella

$ python x.py
Enter name: x
The name that you searched for is absent!
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this solution opened my mindset <33

Answer (score 0):

An improvement to the answer above is using the `else` clause of the `for` loop. This way you don't need the `found` variable and the second `if`:

```py
names = [["alex","tiffany"],["richard","bella"],["bruno","jessica"]]
name = input("Enter name: ")
for item in names:
    if name == item[0]:
        print(item[1])
        break
else:
    # This code will be executed if the for loop runs till its end
    # without 'break' being called.
    print("The name that you searched for is absent!")
```

Comment: thank you so much for your solution. I will keep in my mind :))